# python - How do I define arguments in a function that are optional

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have this code:

```
async def send_log(title: str, guild: discord.Guild, description: str, color: discord.Color, file: discord.File):
  log_channel = guild.get_channel(1083504881744224367)
  embed = discord.Embed(
    title=title,
    description=description,
    color=color,
    file=file
  )
```

but I want the `file: discord.File` argument to be optional because I call this function multiple times and I only want to file option once.

I know its possible, but I don't know how to do it. Could someone tell me?

Comment: Just give the parameter a default value: `def send_log(..., file: Optional[discord.File] = None): ...` It's not clear if that's what you actually want, though. Does `discord.Embed` require a `file` argument, or is it optional for that function as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sounding like you want to pass the argument once and then invoke the function multiple times with the same argument.

One option for doing that is to have a function that returns the log sending function.

```py
def send_log_setup(guild: discord.Guild):
    async def send_log(title: str, description: str, color: discord.Color, file: discord.File):
        log_channel = guild.get_channel(1083504881744224367)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=title,
            description=description,
            color=color,
            file=file
        )
    return send_log


log_sender_for_guild = send_log_setup(guild)

log_sender_for_guild(title, description, color, file)
```

You can then call `log_sender_for_guild` and it will always use the same guild that you initially passed in when setting up the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
async def send_log(title: str, guild: discord.Guild, description: str, color: discord.Color, file: discord.File = None):
    log_channel = guild.get_channel(1083504881744224367)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=title,
        description=description,
        color=color
    )
    
    if file is not None:
        embed.set_image(url="attachment://" + file.filename)
    
    await log_channel.send(embed=embed, file=file)
```

By default, the file argument will be None. However, if you want to include the file, you can pass it as an argument.

For example, without file argument:

```
await send_log(title, description, color)
```

With file:

```
my_file = discord.File("my_image.png")
await send_log(title, description, color, file=my_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `functools.partial` to get a function that calls `send_log` with the `file` argument set to a fixed value:

```
from functools import partial

# async def send_log(...):
#     ...

send_log = partial(send_log, file=some_file)
```

so you can then call it without the `file` argument:

```
send_log(some_title, some_guild, some_description, some_color)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use **kwargs. See this example:

```
async def send_log(title, guild, **kwargs):
    for key, val in kwargs.items():
        if key == 'file':
        # this is only called if file is passed as a kwarg
             print(f'The file is {val}')

log = send_log('my_title', 'my_guild', file='my_file')
asyncio.run(log)
```

You could also simply set file equal to None as default, assuming discord.Embed *file* argument is defaulted to None as well. Then you don't have to pass it. Note that arguments with default values have to be placed at the end of the function:

```
async def send_log(title, description, color, file = None):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=title,
        description=description,
        color=color,
        file=file
    )
log_with_file = send_log('my_title', 'my_description', 'my_color', 'my_file')
log_without_file = send_log('my_title', 'my_description', 'my_color')
```